# Django cannot find url pattern request from Angular

Tags: django, angular, http-status-code-404

Angular 8, Django 3. I have done the same routing and urls, views, services a hundred times but this one route will not work for some reason and i dont know why..

Angular:

**html (with link)**

```
<h2>My Restaurants</h2>

<ul *ngFor = "let restaurant of restaurants">
    <a [routerLink]="['/ordersummary', restaurant.id]">Orders</a>
</ul>
```

**app.routing.module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'ordersummary/:id', component:OrderSummaryComponent}
];
```

**OrderSummaryComponent**

```
export class OrderSummaryComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private orderservice:OrderService,
    private router: ActivatedRoute) { }

  id;
  orders;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.router.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
    this.getrestaurantorders(this.id)}

  getrestaurantorders(id){
    this.orderservice.restaurantorders(id).subscribe(
      x => this.orders = x )}}
```

**OrderService**

```
export class OrderService {

private baseUrl2 : string ='http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/'
private restaurantordersUrl : string = this.baseUrl2+'restaurantorders/'

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient) { }

  restaurantorders(id):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get<any>(this.restaurantordersUrl+id)
  }
```

Django

**urls.py**

```
#base urls
urlpatterns = [
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),

#users urls
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'restaurantorders/<int:pk>', RestaurantOrders.as_view(), name='restaurantorders'),
    ]
```

**views.py**

```
class RestaurantOrders(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = RestaurantOrderSerializer
    queryset = Orders.objects.all()
```

**serializers.py**

```
class RestaurantOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    recipe = RecipeSerializerName
    customer = CustomerSerializerShort
    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = '__all__'
```

I know that Angular is asking for the correct url because the error i get is `"Http failure response for http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/restaurantorders/2: 404 Not Found"`. But the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/restaurantorders/2` url is right there... i dont understand, all of my other requests work. I have restarted the server, maybe restart Pycharm next..

Answer (score 0):

not sure if anyone will run into this problem.. but the issue here was that the `pk` value in my url pattern was for a `Restaurant` object, and my `serializers.py` was querying the `Orders` model.